# How to merge one dimensional array and two dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array one is `two dimensional` and second is `one dimensional` and want to merge in a two dimensional array.

For Example :

```
# array1
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 598          
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 599        
        )
)
# array2
Array
(       
    [id] => 66    
)

#resultant array
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 598
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 599
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 66         
        )
)
```

In above example `array1` and `array2` are two input array and want to result as `resultant array`.

I have tried `array_merge` php function but it is not working.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to add an element it will work:

```
$array1[] = $array2;
```

If you want to create a new array it should work:

```
<?php
$array1 = [
    0 => ['id' => 598],
    1 => ['id' => 599],
];    
$result_array = $array1;    
$array2 = [
    'id' => 66,
];

$result_array[] = $array2;    
print_r($result_array);    
?>
```

In this case just add to new element in `$array1` an `$array2`.

If you have more items in `$array2` you can do it like follows:

```
$result_array = $array1; 
foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
    $result_array[] = [$key => $value];
}
print_r($result_array);
```

Comment: It is not working. `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 598
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 599
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 66
        )

)`

Comment: It does for me. Check for more info there: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e63fe6f45753cacd6c1040a731c7290e70162439

Comment: No I want to create a new `two dimensional` array.

Comment: Check now: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/48f571c7f605bbdda174f87cda77fcacd88045d4
Also updated code in answer.

Comment: But How to identify it is a `one dimensional` or `two dimensional`? Because these are dynamic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129250/discussion-between-karol-gasienica-and-vinaya-maheshwari).

Comment: you can just check which array has `$array[0]` set, like `isset($array[0])`. 
And you would know which one is numeric and according to your code which is two dimension

Comment: Thanks, it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value from [array_value](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) then assign the `id` key to your values and then [merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) your array.

```
$array1 = array(
    array('id' => "2"),
    array('id' => "3"),
);

$array2 = array(
    'id' => "1"
);

$array2['id'] = array_values($array2);

$data = array_merge($array2,$array1);
```

Comment: I can't do this, because I am getting array1, array2 and more like dynamically from database.

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari try my updated answer